# When Java evaluates a conjunction (<boolean exp1> && <boolean exp2>), does it eval exp2 if exp1 is false?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, boolean, expression, evaluation

I'm wondering if it's guaranteed that in a Java program, the boolean expression on the right of a conjunction (exp2 above) will NOT be evaluated as long as the expression on the left (exp1) evaluated to false. I'm wondering because I have an expression like the following:

```
if (var != null && var.somePredicate())
   // do something
```

If Java is not guaranteed to stop evaluating `(var != null && var.somePredicate())` after it sees that `var` is null, then it may try to evaluate `var.somePredicate()` which would throw a NullPointerException.

So my question is, does Java guarantee a certain behavior when it comes to this? Or would it be safer to write

```
if (var != null)
{
   if (var.somePredicate())
      // do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification, [15.23 Conditional-And Operator &&](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> The `&&` operator is like `&` (§15.22.2), but **evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true**.

So the language spec guarantees that the right-hand side of your expression will not be evaluated if the left hand side is false.

Answer (score 5):

No, java uses [Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If `expr1` is `false`, `expr2` will not be evaluated, thus your `&&` usage is perfectly safe.

Also, if you have `if (exp1 || exp2) { .. }` - `exp2` will not be evaluated if `exp1` is `true`.

Comment: That's not lazy evaluation, it's short-circuit.  I don't believe Java itself supports lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Mat: according to wikipedia: `Short-circuit evaluation of Boolean control structures is sometimes called "lazy".` so we are both right. [Though I believe the short-circuit terminology is indeed better - I'll edit, thanks.]

Answer (score 2):

Let us perform our own experiment by looking directly at the opcodes that are generated from this sample code:

```
public class Compare {

        public static void main(String... args) {
          boolean t = true;
          boolean f = false;
          if(f && t) {
            System.out.println("Both true");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("One false");
          }
        }

}
```

`javap -v` generates:

```
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iconst_0
   3:   istore_2
   4:   iload_2
   5:   ifeq    23
   8:   iload_1
   9:   ifeq    23
   12:  getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   15:  ldc #3; //String No
   17:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   20:  goto    31
   23:  getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   26:  ldc #5; //String Yes
   28:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   31:  return
```

The relevant opcodes are `ifeq` for my small program. They check to see if the variables are equal to 0, and jump a certain number of operations forward if they are, in this case, to opcode 23. So if the first `ifeq` evaluates to false it will jump past the second `ifeq` instruction straight to the else statement.

This is called short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use && or ||, java will use short-circuit evaluation (ie not evaluate the second expression unless it needs to)

If you use & or |, java will always evaluate the second expression, even if the first was true

Answer (score 0):

That's safe, Java does short circuit evaluations.