# Parallel Boolean Expression Evaluation in Java

Tags: java, boolean-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Java evaluates a conjunction (<boolean exp1> && <boolean exp2>), does it eval exp2 if exp1 is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445145/when-java-evaluates-a-conjunction-boolean-exp1-boolean-exp2-does-it-ev)

If I have 2 condition say, A and B and I type:

```
A && B
```

Are they both evaluated in parallel and only then it does AND?
For example, if I type `A && false` will it evaluate the `A` condition or it knows it will be false anyway?

And if it's not done in parallel, does it start from the right or left?
(`A && false` VS `false && A`).

Thanks.

EDIT: Got it. Thanks to all!

Comment: It won't. If A is false it won't go to B. And yes. It is right to left.

Comment: The second one (B) is evaluated only if the first one is true. Otherwise, if A is false then A && B is directly evaluated to false, without evaluating B as it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user550413 you should mark an answer as accepted, if you got the answer.

Comment: @eis Yep but it requires to wait 10 mins before I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A && B
```

no,
A is first evaluated and if A is false it skips evaluating B
if A is true then it checks if B is true

```
A && false
```

in this case, A is evaluated first and if A is false, it doesnt check the next condition(false). If A is true then false will be evaluated but as it is false the whole condition would be false.

Comment: OK, so it's left-right evaluation. Does it depend on the compiler or it's guaranteed?

Comment: @user550413 yep, it evaluates from left. and yes its gaureented :P

Answer (score -4):

It will start from **left** to **right**. That is if there are no parentheses involved.

```
if("name".equals(variable1)){}
```

is will get an error when `var1` is null. However, when you use:

```
if(variable1.equals("name")){}
```

it is null safe.

Comment: how is your example code related to how `A && B` is evaluated? Also, it is just plain wrong. If var1 is null, it will break in both cases.

Comment: I see you changed the code. It is however still not related and still wrong. `if(variable1.equals("name"))` is not null safe regards to `variable1`.