# Java post increment and pre increment

Tags: java, increment

The following code in Java:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
boolean d = (a++ > 0 && b-- < 0) || --c < 0;
```

results in the values:

```
a = 1, b = 0, c = -1 and d = true
```

I don't understand why `a` is = 1, because it is a post-increment and should also react the same way that value b does. Also, if I change the `b--` to `--b` it still has no effect on the value of b.

What is the best way of understanding this logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Java evaluates a conjunction (<boolean exp1> && <boolean exp2>), does it eval exp2 if exp1 is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445145/when-java-evaluates-a-conjunction-boolean-exp1-boolean-exp2-does-it-ev)

Comment: in general: such code should be avoided in real life programming, it is overhacking. I understand, here is educational context

Comment: See also [Java short-circuit operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/8097737)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`a++ > 0` returns false, since `a++` return the previous value of `a` (0).

Therefore `b-- < 0` is not evaluated at all, since `&&` is a short circuiting operator. The right operand is only evaluated if the left operand is `true`.

`--c < 0` is evaluated, since the first operand of the `||` operator is `false`, so the second operand must be evaluated.

After `d` is evaluated, the value of `a` is `1`, since `a` was incremented. `b` remains `0`, since `b--` wasn't executed. `c` is `-1` since `--c` was executed.
And `d` is `true` since `--c < 0` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, this helped me understand the concept!

Answer (score 0):

`a++` at moment of comparing is NOT `>0`, so `b` part  is not evaluated, and not incremented.

Second part of `&&` and `||` expressions is not evaluated if cannot change result. For `&&` first `false` determines result `false`.

Analogically, first `true` determines result of `||` (but not here)

Comment: At the time of comparing, `a` **is** 1, but the comparison is about `a++`, which returns the **previous** value of `a` (before the increment), not the **current** value (after increment).

Answer (score 0):

After the expression runs then a will indeed be 1 as the post increment operator has then executed.

During the evaluation of the expression a is 0 as far as the expression is concerned (but a is now 1 for other code), so the first part of the logical OR, your logical AND, is evaluated as false and the b post decrement does not get evaluated.

The second part of the logical or then runs, and the pre-decrement executes to reduce c to -1, which then causes the comparison to evaluate to true, hence d being true.

Expand the different clauses to separate variables and run through a debugger for a more interactive explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a++ OR b--, it passes the value 'a' and 'b' currently holds, and then modifies the variables.

So your expression is simply,

```
boolean d = (0 > 0 && 0 < 0) || -1 < 0;
```

Now while evaluating, (0 > 0 && 0 < 0) -> first expression returns false and you have used short-circuit AND operator. Meaning don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary. As LHS of && returns false, b-- won't be evaluated.

And we have 'd' is true. 
Remember,

Post-increment within expressions --> assign current value first, modify later.

Pre-increment within expressions --> modify first, assign updated value later.

Refer this link for better understanding short circuit operators: 
[Short-Circuit Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: This doesn't explain the [short-circuit operators `&&` and `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/8097737) which causes this behavior.

Comment: @devpuh edited the answer. Explains the behavior now.

Answer (score 0):

a++ effectively means a= a+1
So, the existing value of a (=0) is used for evaluating the expression, and later on the value of a is incremented. So, a becomes 1.

Regarding why b =0 and why --b has the same effect as b--, the value of b is unchanged because of &&. Since a++ > 0 is not satisfied, the next expression b-- < 0 is not evaluated and value of b remains 0. && stops evaluation once the expression evaluates to false, while || stops evaluation once the statement evaluates to false.

Answer (score -1):

Please Execute This code..

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
System.out.println("b = " + --b);
b=0;
System.out.println("b = " + b--);
System.out.println("a = " + a++);
a=0;
System.out.println("a = " + ++a);
System.out.println("c = " + c--);
c=0;
System.out.println("c = " + --c);
a=b=c=0;
boolean d = (a++ > 0 && --b < 0) || --c < 0;

System.out.println("d = " + d);
```

I think you understand full logic.

Comment: When a person asks a question is that it does not understand, it is better a detailed answer for this answer to be useful to others (it is the goal of StackOverflow ...)

Comment: This doesn't explain the [short-circuit operators `&&` and `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/8097737) which causes this behavior.